# How to Capture multiple screenshots (not overriding the previous one)through selenium webdriver using java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to take a multiple screenshots in selenium using java.
For example, I am trying to navigate all the links in my website. While navigating, if there are errors (e.g. page not found, server error), I want to capture all the errors in the screenshots individually. currently it's overriding the previous one.

```
if(driver.getTitle().contains("404")) 
{
    System.out.println("Fail");
       File scrFile = (TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        try {

            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("outputfile"));
            }catch(IOException e){

                e.printStackTrace();
        }

         }

            else

            {

             System.out.println("Pass");

            }
```

Comment: And what is your question? How to create the screenshots; or how to come up with a naming reasonable naming scheme?

Comment: my question was how to create multiple screenshots, i have managed to get the screenshot ,but i dont want to update on the previous screenshot

Comment: You see, that is what I mean with **naming** scheme. Your are overwriting your screen shots because you are always using the same **name** for the file. Thus: you should think of a way of making those file names unique, and probably "telling" (so that the file name tells you about the path it was taken)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do a few things to clean this process up.

1. Put your screenshot code into a function.
2. Add a date time stamp to your screenshot filename. That will give each file a unique name.
3. Add a short error string to the screenshot filename. That will enable you to quickly see how many of each error type are present. Bonus points for creating a folder for each error type and only placing screenshots of that particular error in that folder.

Your script will look like

```
String imageOutputPath = "the path to the folder that stores the screenshots";
if (driver.getTitle().contains("404"))
{
    takeScreenshotOfPage(driver, imageOutputPath + "404 error " + getDateTimeStamp() + ".png");
}
else if (some other error)
{
    takeScreenshotOfPage(driver, imageOutputPath + "some other error " + getDateTimeStamp() + ".png");
}
else if (yet another error)
{
    takeScreenshotOfPage(driver, imageOutputPath + "yet another error " + getDateTimeStamp() + ".png");
}
```

and the function to take a screenshot

```
public static void takeScreenshotOfPage(WebDriver driver, String filePath) throws IOException
{
    File srcFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    BufferedImage srcImage = ImageIO.read(srcFile);
    ImageIO.write(srcImage, "png", new File(filePath));
}
```

and the function to make a filename friendly date-time stamp

```
public static String getDateTimeStamp()
{
    // creates a date time stamp that is Windows OS filename compatible
    return new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd HH.mm.ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
}
```

What you will end up with are filenames like the below that are neatly sorted by error type, each with a unique file name.

```
404 error Dec 02 13.21.18.png
404 error Dec 02 13.22.29.png
404 error Dec 02 13.22.39.png
some other error Dec 02 13.21.25.png
some other error Dec 02 13.22.50.png
some other error Dec 02 13.22.56.png
yet another error Dec 02 13.21.34.png
yet another error Dec 02 13.23.02.png
yet another error Dec 02 13.23.09.png
```

Comment: You can, of course, modify the date time stamp to whatever format you want by changing the format in `SimpleDateFormat()`. This would be even more useful if you put some info about the page it was on or the link that was clicked or ... anything else. You might be better off logging a lot of this info about page, links, etc. and then reference the filename of the corresponding screenshot.

Comment: Thanks Jeffc for your detailed script, i have used your logic with some minor changes its works great

Answer (score 1):

To stop overwriting the output file you would have to give every screenshot a unique name.
Somewhere in the code, create the counter

```
int counter = 1;
```

then

```
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("outputfile" + counter));
counter++;
```

So the counter gives the destination file a different name after every copyFile.

Comment: You could add some hints to also add information to the filename that indicates about error path or such thing. Just counting up files will for sure help, but will give him a lot of nothing-saying filenames in the end.

Comment: Yes its just counting the files, there is nearly 800 pages so we dont know how many of them are broken pages, so it is hard for to give a unique name for every screenshot

Comment: A downside to this approach not mentioned is that if you run the script a second time, it will overwrite these screenshots. You may even end up with a mix of last run and this run depending on how many new screenshots are taken.

Answer (score 1):

You can use current Date Time Stamp and append this with the image format